# Creating a for loop to do a to.String to my array list

Tags: java, arrays

Im currently making a shopping store application, I have 6 classes. 1 for products where it defines the fields for products in the store, another for the shopping basket, one for the GUI and the rest for listeners.

I need to be able to run a method that runs through an array list and running the to.String method on it and returning it as String. Here is what I have at the moment,

```
private ArrayList<OrderItem> basket = new ArrayList<OrderItem>();

public String createArrayText () {
    for (int i = 0; i < OrderItem.size(); i++){
        if (i == OrderItem.size() - 1){
            return ordersText ;
        }
    }
}
```

`ordersText` is a variable I made at the top of my shopping cart class.

This was my first start at it however I'm getting a error on the .size and obviously missing some key components.

One thing Extra is that each item created is added to the array list, each item has a unique order number.

Comment: You need to share more details, especially your OrderItem.

Comment: you wish to convert the entire array and return it. or just a specific index of the array?

Comment: The reason you're getting an error on the `.size()` is that you're calling it on the `OrderItem` class, not any object that has a size. Your loop doesn't make sense on a number of levels. What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Tell us less irrelevant information (I don't really care that you have 6 classes), tell us more relevant information (what are you trying to do for that little method?)

Answer (score 2):

```
Arrays.toString(basket);
```

Is that what you're looking for? If not, you need to explain a little better.

Comment: This should go as a comment!

Answer (score 0):

You generally speaking loop over a List like this (Java 7, it's called enhanced for loop):

```
for (TYPE TEMP_NAME : COLLECTION) {
}
```

That's the overall syntax. TYPE is the type of item in the list, yours are Object's in the given code. TEMP_NAME is the temporary name you want each entry to be referred as. COLLECTION is the list/array/stack/queue or other Collection.

Concretely:

```
for (Object o : basket) {
    // if basket contains 10 entries the line will run 10 times. each new run contains a different object with name o
}
```

Normally when building strings it's preferred to use StringBuilder. We can skip that as it's "only" performance that you gain from it. We'll do it with a regular String. So:

1. Create an empty string that will get longer and longer
2. Loop the collection/array/list
3. Append each object's .toString() to the string from 1)

e.g.

```
String myReturnString = "";
for (Object o : basket) {
    myReturnString = myReturnString + " // " + o.toString();
}
return myReturnString;
```

**Notes:**

Your loop with an index is fine. You can do it that way too, if you want to.

The line of code that appends the string has a " // " separator between each entry. You can pick whatever you like. You can also simplify it to be `myReturnString += " // " + o.toString();`